# Sublime Text 2: Auto fix indentation for javascript?

Tags: javascript, sublimetext2

Here's some sample code I have, currently I'm set to only indent using 4 spaces at a time. Is there a way to highlight a block of javascript and press a single button or menu option to format it nicely like so:

Before:

```
app.get('/csvtest', function (req, res) {
  MyModel.find(function (err, mymodel) {
    if (!err) {
      var csv = [];
      _.each(mymodel, function(obj) {
       csv.push(obj['mymodel']);
      });
      res.send(csv.join());
    } else {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
});
```

After:

```
app.get('/csvtest', function (req, res) {
    MyModel.find(function (err, mymodel) {
        if (!err) {
            var csv = [];
            _.each(mymodel, function(obj) {
                csv.push(obj['mymodel']);
            });
            res.send(csv.join());
        } else {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 150, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/jdc0589/JsFormat) is a tool for this.  Found it on the [sublime forums](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=2430).

- [Install Package control](https://sublime.wbond.net/installation)
- Run Package Control: Install Package from the command palette. Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> (Windows) or <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to open the command palette
- Search for `jsFormat` and hit enter
- `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `f` to format

Comment: This links to a GitHub page. How do you use it?

Comment: @Imray I added a little more detail to my answer. Hope you have resolved this

Comment: To add `https://github.com/jdc0589/JsFormat` as a Package Control repository in sublime you go to Preferences->Package Control->"Package Control: add Repository" and "Package Control: Install Package"

Comment: I had to type "Format" to get a "Format Javascript" option. Might help someone else who couldn't get these answers to work verbatim

Comment: Thanks @CQM, I'll update these instructions, they seem to be stale.

Comment: Nice tip, but there are some missing steps: restart sublime, run "Format: Javascript" command from the palette when needed (Ctrl + Alt + F) shortcut in mac.

Answer (score 40):

You could give [JsFormat](https://github.com/jdc0589/JsFormat) a go. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> formats the selected text.

Answer (score 37):

You can **select all your code** (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) and use the in-app functionality, **Reindent (Edit -> Line -> Reindent)**. It will format your code with looking at the Sublime's tab/intent setting.

**Alternatively:** You can use [**JsFormat**](https://github.com/jdc0589/JsFormat) formatting plugin for Sublime Text 2 if you would like to have more customizable settings on how to format your code to addition to the Sublime Text's default tab/indent settings.

https://github.com/jdc0589/JsFormat

**More info how to install JsFormat to your Sublime IDE:**  You can easily install JsFormat with using Package Control (Preferences -> Package Control) Open package control then type install, hit enter. Then type "js format" and hit <kbd>enter</kbd>, you're done. (The package controller will show the status of the installation with success and errors on the bottom left bar of Sublime)

**Setting the short cut:** Add the following line to your key bindings (Preferences -> Key Bindings User)

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+2"], "command": "js_format"}
```

I'm using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>, you can change this short cut key whatever you want to.

**My opinion:** JsFormat is a good one, definitely worth to try it!

Comment: Thanks a lot - your first answer is really easy and helpful! Didn't know there existed an option for that :)

Comment: Kudos for your 1st answer that helps people without internet connection.

Answer (score 7):

If you specifically want to go from 2 to 4 spaces, click on the tab menu in the lower right corner. Click "convert indentation to tabs", change width to 4, then "convert indentation to spaces."

Answer (score 2):

The fastest way to do this, in general, is with a regex:

- Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Enable the *Regular Expression* button to the bottom-left (or press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>)
- Enter `^(\s+)` in *Find What*
- Enter `\1\1` in *Replace With*
- Click <kbd>Replace All</kbd> to the right

This will double the number of prefixed spaces (bringing 2 spaces to 4). The replace window can then be left open to easily apply this to multiple files.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Sublime Text 2 already has what you want (maybe they added this feature more recently).

Whether you're wanting to change the number of Spaces or you're wanting to convert Spaces to Tabs, you can use this path: **View > Indentation**

Within that dropdown menu you have the option to **Convert Indentation to Tabs**, to **Convert Indentation to Spaces**, or to choose how many Spaces the **Tab Width (1-8)** should be.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This doesn't answer the question that OP asked. He wants the inside of blocks to be more indented than the block declaration.

Comment: @wilbur is right. OP was looking for a formatter hotkey extension of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

Install jsFormat using [PackageControl](https://packagecontrol.io/installation) by selecting jsFormat from the **Install Package** menu.

Then do this to auto-format your code:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

It is also helpful to review the jsLint recommendations for formatting. 
You can install the jsLint package and validate with formatting options enabled.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>