# Trouble with my brackets

Tags: java, string, list, tic-tac-toe, brackets

I am coding in Java and I have a final project due friday and I've done the whole thing  but I can't fix my brackets at the end so the whole thing is messed up.  Also for some reason the tag List won't work in my code. Please see below.  I know they are both easy fixes but I can't seem to figure it out! any help is appreciated. thanks! what brackets do i need to add/fix?

edited!
everywhere where there is doesn't call back into my class position where 
i defined them.
bestMove
gameEnd
win
move

```
package ttt;
import ttt.position;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.text.Position;

public class Game {

position position = new position();
// the word button has a red mark next to the semicolon
protected Component button; 


public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        private Game game;
        private int idx;

        public void run() {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Java TTT");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));
            game = new Game();
            final JButton[] buttons = new JButton[9];
            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                idx = i;
                final JButton button = new JButton();
                buttons[i] = button;
                button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
                button.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                button.setOpaque(true);
                button.setFont(new Font(null, Font.PLAIN, 100));
                button.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
                    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
                    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}
                    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
                    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
                    @Override
                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                        button.setText("" + game.position.turn);
                        game.move(idx);
                            if (!game.position.gameEnd()) {
                                int best = game.position.bestMove();
                                buttons[best].setText("" + game.position.turn);
                                game.move(best);
                            }
                            if (game.position.gameEnd()) {
                                String message = "";
                                if (game.position.win('x')) {
                                    message = "You won! (Mr. Lebron I made the game let you win, I think that deserves an A [Quit to play again])";
                                } else if (game.position.win('o')) {
                                    message = "Computer won! (I think I still deserve an A [Quit to play again])";
                                } else {
                                    message = "It's a tie! (Good try though [Quit to play again])";
                                }

                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);

                            }
                        }
                });
                frame.add(button);
            }
            // realize components
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    } );

}

protected void move(int idx) 
{
// the words position
    position = position.move(idx); 
//the following bracket
}
```

}

position class

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class position {
public char[] board;
public char turn;
public int dim = 3;
private Integer mm;

public position() {
    this.board = "       ".toCharArray();
    this.turn = 'x';

}

public position(char[] board, char turn) {
    this.board = board;
    this.turn = turn;
}

public position(String str) {
    this.board = str.toCharArray();
    this.turn = 'x';
}

public position(String str, char turn) {
    this.board = str.toCharArray();
    this.turn = turn;
}

public String toString() {
    return new String(board);
}

public position move(int idx) {
    char[] newBoard = board.clone();
    newBoard[idx] = turn;
    return new position(newBoard, turn == 'x' ? 'o' : 'x');
}

// list type can't be generic edit

public Integer[] possibleMoves() {
    java.util.List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        if (board[i] == ' ') {
            list.add(i);
        }

    }
    Integer[] array = new Integer[list.size()];
    list.toArray(array);

    return array;
}

public boolean win_line(char turn, int start, int step) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (board[start + step * 1] != turn) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

// calling win here

public boolean win(char turn) {
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
        if (win_line(turn, i * dim, 1) || win_line(turn, i, dim)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    if (win_line(turn, dim - 1, dim - 1) || win_line(turn, 0, dim + 1)) {
        return true;
    }
    {
        return false;
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("null")
public int minimax() {
    if (win('x')) {
        return 100;
    }
    if (win('o')) {
        return -100;
    }
    if (possibleMoves().length == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    mm = null;
    for (Integer idx : possibleMoves()) {
        Integer value = null;
        if (mm == null || turn == 'x' && mm < value || turn == 'o'
                && value < mm) {
            mm = value;
        }
    }
    return mm + (turn == 'x' ? -1 : 1);
}

// fix game end here
public boolean gameEnd() {

    return win('x') || win('o') || possibleMoves().length == 0;

}

public int bestMove() {
    Integer mm = null;
    int best = -1;
    for (Integer idx : possibleMoves()) {
        Integer value = move(idx).minimax();
        if (mm == null || turn == 'x' && mm < value || turn == 'o'
                && value < mm) {
            mm = value;
            best = idx;
        }
    }
    return best;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the list error you have to import java.util.*

```
import java.util.*
```

Importing LinkedList does not include using list.

Comment: Multiple markers at this line
 - The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments 
  <Integer>
 - The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments 
  <Integer>

Comment: @AndrewRothberg try instantiating it as java.util.List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();

Answer (score 1):

You missed quite a few matching/closing brackets in your code. Not sure where you want to place the method possibleMoves(), but the original code posted should work as follows:

```
public class Game {

    position position = new position();
    // the word button has a red mark next to the semicolon
    protected Component button; 


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            private Game game;
            private int idx;

            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Java TTT");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));
                game = new Game();
                final JButton[] buttons = new JButton[9];
                for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                    idx = i;
                    final JButton button = new JButton();
                    buttons[i] = button;
                    button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
                    button.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                    button.setOpaque(true);
                    button.setFont(new Font(null, Font.PLAIN, 100));
                    button.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
                        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
                        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}
                        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
                        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
                        @Override
                        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                            button.setText("" + game.position.turn);
                            game.move(idx);
                                if (!game.position.gameEnd()) {
                                    int best = game.position.bestMove();
                                    buttons[best].setText("" + game.position.turn);
                                    game.move(best);
                                }
                                if (game.position.gameEnd()) {
                                    String message = "";
                                    if (game.position.win('x')) {
                                        message = "You won! (Mr. Lebron I made the game let you win, I think that deserves an A [Quit to play again])";
                                    } else if (game.position.win('o')) {
                                        message = "Computer won! (I think I still deserve an A [Quit to play again])";
                                    } else {
                                        message = "It's a tie! (Good try though [Quit to play again])";
                                    }

                                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);

                                }
                            }
                    });
                    frame.add(button);
                }
                // realize components
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        }
    }

    protected void move(int idx) 
    {
    // the words position
        position = position.move(idx); 
    //the following bracket
    }
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU THAT FIXED IT! Ive been pulling my hair out trying to get that done. now just onto the list :P

Comment: when i fixed it with the brackets you gave me, now lines 56-65 all have red lines that say the method gameEnd() is undefined for the type position...?

Answer (score 0):

Download an editor like [sublime](http://www.sublimetext.com/) and open the file in that editor.

It will show you each corresponding bracket for each one when you move the cursor to the position of a bracket.

You will find out, if you correct the indentions in your file.

Also you could give jsFormat a go: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12867043/1069083